# linux wifi: how to detect the "connecting" state of an interface?

Tags: wireless-networking, wpa-supplicant

On Linux, is there a (low level) way to know if a wireless interface is currently *trying* to connect to a network?

I failed to find something useful in this respect in `/sys/class/net/<iface>/operstate` and siblings, which mostly seem to provide stable states or stats.

I know `wpa_supplicant` log tells exactly what is going on (and more), but I fail to see any parameters to query the daemon in real time, and I do not want to enable logging and to poll the state as I am on a small platform (stripped down Armbian 4.9.82-ti-r102, Octavo SIP).

For the same reason I will not use any network manager of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what those network managers do, and use wpa_supplicant's socket **control interface** (or its equivalent D-Bus service) to receive live notifications.

For example, [control interface docs](https://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/devel/ctrl_iface_page.html) mention the following events:

> - CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED: EAP authentication started (EAP-Request/Identity received)
> - CTRL-EVENT-EAP-SUCCESS: EAP authentication completed successfully
> - CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED: Indicate successfully completed authentication and that the data connection is now enabled

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the deal. So far I managed to avoid any compiled stuff and use shell only, and this seems to require C and linking against its API. But it is not a real issue anyway, so thanks again for pointing me to a valid solution.

Comment: What API? The libc socket API? That's going to be present in your system _no matter what_.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not want to enable logging and to poll the state as I am on a small platform

Use `wpa_supplicant` with the `-f` option to create a logfile.

```
 -f output file
          Log  output  to  specified  file instead of stdout.
```

then use `grep` to check *if a wireless interface is currently trying to connect to a network* from the logfile . see [my answer on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/429079/153195).

Comment: Thanks but that is precisely what I did not want to do (enable logging and having to poll) ;)

Comment: You don't have to _poll_ files, you can use inotify to follow them...

Comment: sure, but it is still a log file and the watcher gets triggered on each line